# what java time object should be used to compare mysql datetime column?

Tags: mysql, datetime, java-8, jdbctemplate

I have a table like the following

```
CREATE TABLE `MY_TABLE` (
  `CODE` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ADDRESS`  varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `LAST_MODIFIED_IN_UTC` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CODE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is a sample insert that I do

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
(`CODE`,
`ADDRESS`,
`LAST_MODIFIED_IN_UTC`)
VALUES
('PR123',
'dummy address',
UTC_TIMESTAMP(6)
);
```

I use mysql UTC_TIMESTAMP(6) inbuilt function.

Now in my Java code, I execute the following in jdbcTemplate

```
String sql = "SELECT CODE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE LAST_MODIFIED_IN_UTC > ?";

LocalDateTime filterTime = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC())
                    .minusMinutes(120);

how do I pass the localDateTime to jdbcTemplate for query.
```

something like this.

```
 jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, new Object[]{filterTime}, String.class);
```

what java time object should I use here?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL itself recommends `java.sql.Timestamp` to map with `DATETIME` data type.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)

But often, people use `java.util.Date` to map for it.